# Can't set Network Adapter for Hyper-V machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I have a windows 2008 Server with hyper-v enabled.  I can't seem to load any network adapter into the virtual machine, it always says "Load Failed".  Im really not sure what I'm doing wrong, or where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your network cards and re-connect them, I would also try to find updated drivers.

What type of card is it, It may not be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new virtual switch and select that one instead.

Here is how: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/19359-hyper-v-virtual-switch-manager.html

Answer (score 0):

I write this just in case it can help someone, I had a similar problem, I wasn't able to see my network adapters in my windows server 2008 hyper-v machine, so the problem was the external switch couldn't be a normal one it has to be legacy external switch, so the steps I followed to resolve this were:

1- Create vm with windows server 2008 and not connected switch.

2- Goes to settings in my virtual machine an remove the not connected network adapter.

3- In settings add hardware - add legacy network adapter and connect to the external switch I had created.

And that's all. It should work like this.